# how to set image in imageview in different shape in IOS?

Tags: ios, imageview, shapes

I am developing an application in IOS in which I want to set an image on in the shape given in the attached image. How can I do that? Please suggest me.

[image]

Comment: Hey you need to clip the image by apply a shape. Let me try whether I can work out one for you.

Comment: I would really appreciate If you can help me out

Comment: Hey, it is done. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hours of hard working. Finally... I have added the green border too.

First of you, you just define the path that can clip the image.

```
- (CGPathRef) pathInRect:(CGRect)rect radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    CGMutablePathRef retPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(retPath, NULL, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y + 2 * radius);

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(retPath, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + 2 * radius);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(retPath, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + radius);

    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y, radius);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL, rect.origin.x + 2 * radius, rect.origin.y, rect.origin.x + radius * 2, rect.origin.y + radius, radius);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(retPath, NULL, rect.origin.x + 2 * radius, rect.origin.y + 2 * radius, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y + 2 * radius, radius);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(retPath);
    return retPath;
}
```

In my old project, I am using drawRect for UITableViewCell, so I reuse the code. The code firstly create a new clipped image based on the path, then draw the image. After that, a border with the same path is drawn too.

```
#define PHOTO_SIDE 40.f
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, PHOTO_SIDE, PHOTO_SIDE);


    //Draw clipped image
    UIImage *image = [Your Image];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(PHOTO_SIDE, PHOTO_SIDE));
    CGPathRef path = [self pathInRect:frame radius:PHOTO_SIDE / 2];
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextClip(context);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, PHOTO_SIDE, PHOTO_SIDE)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [newImage drawInRect:frame];

    //Draw Border
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

[image: Test Image]

Comment: This code is tested and guarantee working. :D

Comment: hello ethan , i am using this code , everything is perfect but border is not getting drawn and its giving me the following warning, can you please help me out here.


<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x14e903b0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: Hello ethan, your code is working perfectly but borders seems not to be there, can you please update your answer?

Comment: Hi rahul, I have tested the code before and as you can see, the screenshot was the result after running the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example:

1. Overlay your `imageView` with a mask image (which has transparent pixels where you want your actual image visibile - like square with hole inside)
2. Add `maskLayer` with the shape you want to the layer of your `imageView`.

Example of `UIImage` category to create round images to give you an idea:

```
+ (instancetype)maskedImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (!image)
        return nil;
    CGFloat dim = MIN(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(dim, dim);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, .0);
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRect){ CGPointZero, size }];
    [bezierPath fill];
    [bezierPath addClip];
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake((dim - image.size.width) * 0.5, (dim - image.size.height) * 0.5);
    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){ offset, image.size }];
    UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return ret;
}
```

Use it like:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
myImageView.image = [UIImage maskedImageWithImage:myImage];
```

To achieve more complicated shape, you essentially need to modify the `bezierPath` which is effectively a clipping mask.